# Send e-mail from an action

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise.

I want to create an action which sends e-mails among other things.

The action has two input parameters of type "string". 
I am able to use the parameters when I create an entity or in conditions in branches.

However, I am not able to use these parameters when I choose the "Send e-mail" task or if I try to create a new entity record of type e-mail. 
The expression designer shows "Search for: Arguments" but the list of arguments is empty.

Any ideas why that is the case?

Edit: Image one shows the action with 2 string argumengs. Image 2 shows that I can use the argument as topic of a letter. Image 3 shows that the argument list is empty when I try to do the same for an e-mail.

I recreated the action, changed the computer, used a different user account.

[Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie3mz.jpg)

[Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZjIv.jpg)

[E-Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf0z6.jpg)

Comment: How are you trying to use this arguments? You can use only arguments of the same type, so you should be able to use them for example a field that is of type "Single line of text"

Comment: I'll try and guess the root cause: you can't provide the addresses (from, to, etc.) as strings to the email, you need entity references to valid activity parties

Comment: @PawelGradecki I tried to use it for the subject/topic of the e-mail. That should work?

Comment: It should work. And I just checked in my system that it works. Maybe re-create your action, as it looks like some metadata error in your system... I just created an action with an input string argument and can successfully use it inside topic of the email.

Comment: On a side note: which version is it ? question doesn't match the tag

Comment: @Alex It is Dynamics 2016, but as far as I see there is not tag for that version

Comment: Is that a calculated field?

Comment: @ArunVinoth No, it is not a calculated field